# Binding data of celltemple

Tags: c, wpf

```
 <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
      <GridViewColumn Header="Tên Mặt Hàng" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Ten}">
          <GridViewColumn.CellTemple>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Ten">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ten}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn.CellTemple>
      </GridViewColumn> </GridView>
```

every one, I have code, I want to binding Text of textBlock to use data again in other files, so what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a ViewModel of this view. And bind the viewModel property to this view. For example:

```
public class NamViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string _ten;
    public string Ten {
        get
        {
           return _ten;
        }
        set 
        {
           _ten = value;
           this.RaisePropertyChanged("Ten");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can bind this viewModel in the constructor of the view. For example:

```
public partial class NamView : Window {
    public NamView() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new NamViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: tks man I searched all day :(( if you don't, I wouldn't be able to find it forever, Now I will test it <3

Comment: Can you give me the xaml code when binding that data in textblock?

Comment: Currently I do not have a computer here but the problem is solved and thank you for your help